# Jmeter - BeanShellSampler - scripting

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using a CSV Data Set Config to read a CSV file.

In BeanShell Sampler i have written

```
1: ${varAcc};${AccountNumber};
2: vars.put("${varAcc}","${AccountNumber}");
```

When there was only line 1 the output is perfect which comes from csv file.
When I add the 2nd line it gives error

> ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` A1;1003963;  vars.put("A1","1003963");

Do I import any package ?

Comment: what is your objective? why are you using BeanShell Sampler?

Comment: Is it the complete error message? Also, please add screenshot of the BeanShell. I don't see any issue in current code as it worked for me.

Comment: What is the purpose of Line 1?
1: ${varAcc};${AccountNumber};

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate:

```
vars.put("varAcc", vars.get("AccountNumber"));
```

It will put value from **AccountNumber** variable into **varAcc** variable. I imagine you are trying to do that?

Comment: Yes true. I am trying to do the same. But I see the same error in jmeter log.